# Show that $\text{dim}(W_1)=\text{dim}(W_1+\mathrm{span}(v))$ if and only if $v \in W_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Sorry for the vague title but cant come with a better one, so I have the following question:

> Let $v_1,v_2,..,v_k,v$ be vectors in a vector space $V$. Define the workspace: $W_1=\mathrm{span}({v_1,v_2,..,v_k})$ and $W_2=\mathrm{span}({v_1,v_2,..,v_k,v})$. Show that $\text{dim}(W_1)=\text{dim}(W_2)$ iff $v\in W_1$

So I proceeded in the following way:

Let us consider that $v \in W_1$then we can write: $$v=\sum_i^ka_iv_i$$
or $$0=(-1)v+\sum_i^ka_iv_i$$

Now we can see that the above equation is a linear combination of subspace vectors $W_2$. However since $W_2=\mathrm{span}({v_1,v_2,..,v_k,v})$, then ${v_1,v_2,..,v_k,v}$ must be a set of linearly indepedent vectors but the linear combination mentioned above says otherwise. So $v$ don't belong to $W_2$. Hence we can conclude that $$\text{dim}(W_1)=\text{dim}(W_2)$$
However my instructor has told me its entirely wrong with no explanation given, so I really need help to point out faults in my solution. Thank you

Comment: You say "a set of linear vectors". Do you mean "linearly independent"?

Comment: @jwhite Yes sorry, I forgot the word, I will edit

Comment: $v_1,\ldots, v_k,v$ don't have to be linearly independent. Even $v_1,\ldots, v_k$ don't have to be. There's no such assumption, and it is not needed. Otherwise the conclusion is trivial because $dim W_1=k$ and $dim W_2=k+1$. Such reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: A spanning set means a set of vectors such that every vector is a linear combination of them. This set does **not** need to be linearly independent.

Comment: @freakish Ok, I got my mistake, so what other way I can proceed, since I am pretty new to linear algebra, I need guidance.

Comment: The span of $\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\}$ is the set of all vectors which can be represented in the form $\sum_{j=1}^ka_jv_j$ for some scalars $a_j$. Similarly, the span of $\{v_1,\ldots, v_k,v\}$ is the set of all vectors which can be represented in the form $av+\sum_{j=1}^k a_jv_j$. If $v\in \text{span}\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\}$, then these two sets are the same (and therefore have the same dimension). That's a hint for one direction.

Comment: For the other direction, I use the fact that any spanning set can be reduced to a basis. That is, we go down the list $\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\}$ and any time we find a "redundant" vector (a vector in the span of the previous vectors), throw it out. This doesn't change the span (see the previous hint). For this, it's important to note that, by convention, the zero vector is in the span of the empty set, so we throw out any zeros that we find, too. So if we reduce $\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\}$ to $\{v_{j_1}, \ldots, v_{j_d}\}$ then $\dim  W_1=d$.

Comment: In that case, if $v\notin W_1$, then $\{v_{j_1}, \ldots, v_{j_d},v\}$ is a basis for $W_2$, and $\dim W_2=d+1$.

Comment: Also, note that $\text{dim}(W_1+span(v))=\text{dim}(W_1)+\text{dim}(span(v))-\text{dim}(W_1\cap span(v))$ and $\text{dim}(span(v))=1$.

Comment: It is useless to consider $v_1,\dots,v_k$, or a basis of $W_1$, or that general formula about the dimension of a sum (with $\dim(span(v))=1$ **or $\bf0$**). Simply assume $W_1$ is finite dimensional and set $W_2=W_1+Kv$ (where $K$ is your field of scalars: "usually" for beginners $K=\Bbb R$).

$W_1\subseteq W_2$, hence $\dim W_1=\dim W_2$ iff $W_1=W_2$ i.e. iff $W_2\subseteq W_1$ i.e. iff $v\in W_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one wants to write an answer, I will write one.

> since $W_2=span({v_1,v_2,..,v_k,v})$, then ${v_1,v_2,..,v_k,v}$ must be a set of linearly indepedent vectors

This is not correct, because the list $v_1,\ldots,v_k,v$ does not have to be linearly independent (as already pointed out in the comments).

Note that every $w_1\in W_1$ can be written as
$$w_1=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k+0v,$$
which means that $w_1\in W_2$. Therefore,
$$W_1\subseteq W_2.$$

($\Longrightarrow$) Suppose $\dim W_1=\dim W_2$. Then $W_1=W_2$, because $W_1\subseteq W_2$ and $\dim W_1=\dim W_2$. Since $v\in W_2$ and $W_1=W_2$, we have $v\in W_1$.

($\Longleftarrow$) Suppose $v\in W_1$. Then,
$$(*) \ \ \ \ \ v=b_1v_1+\cdots+b_kv_k.$$
Let $w_2\in W_2$ be arbitrary, then
$$(**) \ \ \ \ \ w_2=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_kv_k+c_{k+1}v.$$
Substituting $(*)$ into $(**)$, we get
$$w_2=(c_1+b_1c_{k+1})v_1+\cdots+(c_k+b_kc_{k+1})v_k,$$
which means that $w_2\in W_1$. Therefore, $W_2\subseteq W_1$.

Since $W_2\subseteq W_1$ and $W_1\subseteq W_2$, then $W_1=W_2$, which implies $\dim W_1=\dim W_2$.